# How to print commas between two numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have:

```
a=[2;3];
b=[4;5];
c=[1;1];
```

How can I print the result as

```
s=
2,4,1
3,5,1
```

So far I have tried with:

```
a=[2;3];
b=[4;5];
c=[1;1];
s=sprintf('%d,%d,%d\n',a,b,c)
```

but I am not getting the desirable result.

Comment: See `help sprintf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can merge them into a matrix and then do the following:

```
res = [a b c];
str = sprintf('%d,%d,%d\n',res.');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
s = sprintf('%d,%d,%d\n', [a,b,c]')
```

which gives

```
s = 2,4,1
3,5,1
```